# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'angle' referenced before assignment on line 100

Tags: python

This is part of a game I am creating. This is what I have so far.

I've been coding and to test out my code, I ran it and it had an error like this:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'angle' referenced before assignment on line 100.

I've never experienced this error before and I don't know what it means. Someone help me!

```
import turtle
import random

def main():
  wn=turtle.Screen();
  Gameturtle=turtle.Turtle()

  Setupuser(Gameturtle,wn)
  Setupcontrols(Gameturtle,wn

 def Setupuser(myTurtle,window):
  window.bgcolor("white")
  #width=x height=y
  window.setup (width=400, height=400, startx=0, starty=0)
  myTurtle.speed(2)
  myTurtle.shape('turtle')
  myTurtle.penup()
  myTurtle.delay(0)
  myTurtle.left(90)

  myTurtle.mainloop()

  window.exitonclick ()

def Setupcontrols(turtle, window):
  window.onkey(lambda: turtle.goto(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor()+15), 'w')
  window.onkey(lambda: turtle.goto(turtle.xcor()-15, turtle.ycor()), 'a')
  window.onkey(lambda: turtle.goto(turtle.xcor()+15, turtle.ycor()), 'd')
  window.onkey(lambda: turtle.goto(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor()-15), 's')

  window.listen()

def Randomanglegenerator(t,len, hei):
  XYcordguesser = random.randrange(1,4)
  print(XYcordguesser)
  Xcord=0
  Ycord=0
  if XYcordguesser==1:
    Xcord = random.randrange(-1/2 * len, 1/2 * len)
    Ycord=0.5 * hei 
  if XYcordguesser==2:
    Ycord = random.randrange(-0.5 * hei, 0.5 * hei)
    Xcord=0.5 * len
  if XYcordguesser==3:
    Xcord = random.randrange(-0.5 * len, 0.5 * len)
    Ycord=-0.5 * hei
  if XYcordguesser==4:
    Ycord = random.randrange(-0.5 * hei, 0.5 * hei)
    Xcord=-0.5 * hei
  print(Xcord)
  print(Ycord)

  quadrant=0

  if quadrant == 1:
    angle = random.randrange(350, 170, 0)
    t.forward

  t.ht()
  t.shape("turtle")
  t.speed(5)
  t.penup()
  t.left(90)
  t.setposition(Xcord,Ycord)
  t.setheading(angle)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error arises from this part of your code:

```
quadrant = 0

if quadrant == 1:
    angle = random.randrange(350, 170, 0)
    t.forward
...
t.setheading(angle)
```

In the event that `quadrant != 1`, no value is assigned to the variable `angle` and you will get the `UnboundLocalError` error. This is always going to be the case as the previous line assigns `quadrant` a value of zero. You need to check the logic of what you're trying to do here.

You also need to make sure that a value is assigned to `angle` in all cases, or move the `t.setheading(angle)` call inside your `if` statement.